# Symfony2 inner join return proxies in result arrray

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I know that this query work's like a charm:

```
$result = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('banner','customer')
    ->from("MyBundle:Banner", 'banner')
    ->innerJoin('banner.customer', 'customer')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

later, in a view, i can iterate and print `{{banner.name}}` and `{{banner.customer.name}}` without an extra query to database.

But, the same query with a little change on the `innerJoin`:

```
$result = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('banner','customer')
    ->from("MyBundle:Banner", 'banner')
    ->innerJoin('MyBundle:Customer', 'customer', 'WITH', 'customer.id = banner.customer')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();

foreach ($result as $e)
    echo get_class($e).'<br/>';
die(1);
```

this print:

```
MyBundle\Entity\Banner
Proxies\__CG__\MyBundle\Entity\Customer
MyBundle\Entity\Banner
MyBundle\Entity\Banner
Proxies\__CG__\MyBundle\Entity\Customer
MyBundle\Entity\Banner
MyBundle\Entity\Banner
Proxies\__CG__\MyBundle\Entity\Customer
MyBundle\Entity\Banner
```

So, if i iterate this result, expecting a `MyBundle\Entity\Banner` object, i will be in trouble, so:

Is this the expected result doing the `innerJoin` like the second example?
Is an extra `function call`, `syntax` or `doctrine/symfony setup` needed to make it work like the first example?

thanks

Comment: You do have `OneToOne` relation set, right? If so, that `WITH` totally unnecessary...

Comment: No, is `oneToMany`, one customer have many banner

Comment: Oh, in that case did you make that `oneToMany` bidirectional?

Comment: Can you show me your mappings? Because of the first lower case letter in `oneToMany`, I assume you use `YAML` to describe relations. Check my answer - this is how I think your relations should look like...

Comment: Yes, each one have the relation declared, if that is what you mean

Comment: So, if you remove `WITH`, does it help?

Comment: I get this if i remove the `WITH`: [Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got end of string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42672/discussion-between-jperovic-and-kstro21)

Answer (score 0):

Use bidirectional `oneToMany` and remove `WITH` from `innerJoin` call:

```
Customer:
  type: entity
  oneToMany:
    banners:
      targetEntity: Banner
      mappedBy: customer
Banner:
  type: entity
  manyToOne:
    customer:
      targetEntity: Customer
      inversedBy: banners
      joinColumn:
        name: customer_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: I get this if i remove the WITH: [Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got end of string.